# IndexError but I don't know what is wrong

Tags: python

```
opponent = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I want just the first element in my list 'opponent', therefore I then code:

```
opponent = int(opponent[0])
```

I use this to then count the number of 'opponent's there are in one of my other lists.

```
if wongames.count(opponent) == 2:
...blablabla
```

> It says my submission raised an exception of type IndexError at the
>   line.  'opponent = int(opponent[0])'.

Why is this? How do I fix this? :(

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should post your code. And why are you casting an int to int here? int(oppponent[0]).

Comment: Change variables name `opponent` to something else. You are redeclaring `opponent` list just to a integer in the step `opponent = int(opponent[0])`. So you can't use it back as a list.

Answer (score 3):

Your list of opponents is called `opponent`, and later on in your code you do:

```
opponent = int(opponent[0])
```

overriding the earlier `opponent` list, so now the `opponent` name refers to an integer instead.

Next time you do the same again:

```
opponent = int(opponent[0])
```

You're trying to access `[0]` index of an integer, which obviously doesn't work because integers cannot be indexed.

**Solution:** Simply use a different name for the two variables. I'd call the list `opponents` instead:

```
opponents = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
opponent = opponents[0]
```

Notice that since they're already integers in the list, you don't need `int()`. You only need to use `int()` if you want to convert it from one type to another, for example if it was a string `'0'` instead of an integer `0`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's happening there, but I suspect the `indexError` is because you are **assigning the same `opponent` variable to pick the element from the list `opponent`**.

If you run this code snippet for the second iteration, variable `opponent` is **not a list** anymore, maybe that is the reason for the error. Try changing assigning the value to a new variable.

```
opponent = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

## Code block
opponent = int(opponent[0]) # Now opponent is not a list, just a number
if wongames.count(opponent) == 2:
    # do something
```

If the code block is executing for the second time, the error occurs. Try changing the code to something as follows,

```
opponent = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
first_opponent = int(opponent[0]) 
if wongames.count(first_opponent) == 2:
    # do something
```

---

Hope this helps! :)